# Determining the Gradle test execution order

Tags: gradle

I was wondering whether it's possible to obtain information about test execution order somehow.

I have a project in Maven and all the tests are passing. After I migrated the project to Gradle, one of the tests started failing. The test itself is working: when I execute `gradle test -Dtest.single=...`, it passes. However, when I run the tests for the whole project, the test fails.

It's possible that some tests that run before the failing test do not release resources correctly and therefore the test fails. But I need to somehow find out which tests are causing this problem.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but maybe You have tests dependent on each other? You should redesign it.

Comment: This is not the case. Test is standalone, starting an Infinispan instance and fails on:
org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.infinispan when trying to register: type=Cache,name="registryCache(local)",manager="DefaultCacheManager"

This is probably caused by already running Infinispan instance from some other test which failed to close it. Since all my tests are passing when run via maven, I suspect that Gradle uses different test execution order, which leads to test failure. I just need to somehow find original test, which doesn't cleanup after itself.

Comment: Ok, sorry for bad concept.

Comment: No problem at all! I'm glad for any answer :-). Unfortunatelly, I don't have an idea how to debug this. Since I don't exactly know what resource is 'locked' (causing my test to fail) I don't know what should I look for in other tests. I guess all I can do is to check all tests and see whether they shutdown Infinispan instance correctly. Although I would love to compare order in which tests are executed in Gradle vs Maven.

Comment: @Opal Of course, to figure out which test is doing it, you'd have to be able to figure out the test order, so the question would even be relevant in that situation anyway. :)

Comment: Has some similarities with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42442905/1089967)

Answer (score 2):

Tell Gradle to log more events about test processing. There is a documentation how to do that http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html

Answer (score 2):

The [`beforeTest`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:beforeTest(groovy.lang.Closure)) method can be used to output details about each test before it is run, based on a [`TestDescriptor`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestDescriptor.html) for each test:

```groovy
test {
    beforeTest { testDescriptor ->
        println "${testDescriptor.className} > ${testDescriptor.name} STARTED"
    }
}
```