# JUnit tests influence each other

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit

I'm working with a lot of legacy code. There was a JUnit-TestSuite to begin with. When running all tests with gradle, they failed. When running the test in IntelliJ, they worked. We configured gradle to use the test suite.

Now someone reported tests working locally without gradle, but not with gradle. It's time we fix this mess.

Is there a smart way to figure out which test leaves some configuration behind or which tests relies on the other tests?

Comment: Probably its the order of execution, I think IDEs and JUnit in general doesnt warranty an order or execution. As well if there are static variables that are not immutable may be causing some issues. -Sorry for the opinioned based comment.

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way... I'd look for tests with `@BeforeClass`. Test failures will also obviously point you at the offending class. I'd call this bug fixing, and if there were an automated way to fix bugs we'd all be out of the job. If you can get a code coverage report, it might indicate exactly where the failure happens.

Comment: Thanks, @cesaregb, I'll look for static variables!

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Thanks, I'll look for `@BeforeClass`. But I think test failures will not show me the offending class, they will only show me which class did not start with a clean slate, not which other class caused that, right?

Comment: @MelanieB. It won't show what other class causes the issue, but it should help show what interactions caused the failure. I'm not looking at your source code, so I can't say much more beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely cause of this "bleed" from one test into another is mutable static values. By default, all tests are run by the same JVM so a static variable which is "mutated" by one test will be "dirty" in another test.

Mutable statics are evil! I'm working on a codebase currently with mutable statics everywhere and it's a mess. If possible you should refactor to use dependency injection and store mutable state in instances and not statics.

The best workaround is to find the tests which "dirty" the static mutable variables and do

```
@After
public void cleanup() {
  SomeStatic.reset();
}
```

If you can't find the "dirty" test which is causing the issue, you might be forced to do the following in the "failing" test. This is not preferred, and a little hacky

```
@Before
public void cleanBefore() {
   SomeStatic.reset();
}
```

But this has a slight code "smell". Better to find the offending test which "dirties" the mutable static

The "nuclear" option is to run each test in its own jvm. This is a total hack and should be avoided at all costs. It will drastically increase the time it takes to run your tests

```
test {
   forkEvery = 1
}
```

See [Test.forkEvery](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:forkEvery)

Comment: Thank you! I'll look for mutable static values. We have a Settings Class, so I have the strong suspicion there might be something in there. I've never worked with dependency injection, I'll have to look into that. I don't need the gradle trick (even though it's pretty cool), since gradle does run successfully right now using the test suite.

Comment: Each test that mutates the `Settings` statics should call `Settings.reset()` in an `@After` or `@AfterClass` method. Sometimes it's easier to also put a `Settings.reset()` in a `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` too if you can't track down the naughty test

Comment: I know this is an old issue that you've probably got resolved, but I'm looking to add an answer of my own, and want to make sure I'm answering the right question.  I'm a bit confused by this statement: "Now someone reported tests working locally without gradle, but not with gradle."  You state in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442016/junit-tests-influence-each-other#comment72076543_42442905) that tests work with Gradle.  Or is it a matter where they worked in Gradle when run via the suite, but not without?

Answer (score 1):

I recently diagnosed a similar issue in a Gradle Java project, where a test was working when run individually, but not when run as part of the Gradle build.

In order to track down the offending test that was breaking the subsequent test, I first configured Gradle to print out the tests that were run using [`beforeTest`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:beforeTest(groovy.lang.Closure)), so I could tell what all was running prior to my test:

```groovy
test {
    beforeTest { TestDescriptor descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("$descriptor.className#$descriptor.name")
    }
}
```

This printed the tests in the order in which they ran:

```
$./gradlew test
> Task :test
com.example.Test1#firstTest()
com.example.Test1#secondTest()
com.example.Test2#firstTest()
com.example.Test2#secondTest()
com.example.Test3#firstTest()
com.example.Test3#secondTest()
com.example.BrokenTest#brokenTest()

BrokenTest > brokenTest() FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at BrokenTest.java:34

com.example.Test4#firstTest()
com.example.Test4#secondTest()
```

Now that I knew which test classes were running before the broken test, I knew that one (or more) of those tests were causing the test to break.

Next, I added [test filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering) in my Gradle build to only run those tests that ran before the broken test, plus the broken test itself:

```gradle
test {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.Test1'
        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.Test2'
        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.Test3'
        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.BrokenTest'
    }
}
```

After doing a sanity check Gradle build to confirm that the test was still broken, I commented out groups of tests and reran the build until I was able to narrow it down to the test that caused the build to break:

```groovy
test {
    filter {
//        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.Test1'
        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.Test2'
//        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.Test3'
        includeTestsMatching 'com.example.BrokenTest'
    }
}
```

In this example, the build broke when `Test2` was run before BrokenTest, but not when `Test1` or `Test3` were.  Armed with this information, I could dive deeper into what specifically about `Test2` was affecting the system in such a way as to break the other test when it was run after it.

Comment: Thanks for this, a nice step by step way of diagnosing the problem